# Haskell - Sum of the differences between each element in each matrix

Tags: loops, haskell, matrix, iterator, sum

I am very new to Haskell (and functional programming in general) and I am trying to write a function called 
"profileDistance m1 m2" that takes two matrices as parameters and needs to calculate the sum of the differences between each element in each matrix... I might have not explained that very well. Let me show it instead.

The matrices are on the form of: `[[(Char,Int)]]`
where each matrix might look something like this:

```
m1 = [[('A',1),('A',2)],
      [('B',3),('B',4)],   
      [('C',5),('C',6)]]

m2 = [[('A',7),('A',8)],
      [('B',9),('B',10)],   
      [('C',11),('C',12)]]
```

(Note: I wrote the numbers in order in this example but they can be ANY numbers in any order. The chars in each row in each matrix will however match like shown in the example.)

The result (in the case above) would look something like (psuedo code):

```
result = ((snd m1['A'][0])-(snd m2['A'][0]))+((snd m1['A'][1])-(snd m2['A'][1]))+((snd m1['B'][0])-(snd m2['B'][0]))+((snd m1['B'][1])-(snd m2['B'][1]))+((snd m1['C'][0])-(snd m2['C'][0]))+((snd m1['C'][1])-(snd m2['C'][1]))
```

This would be easy to do in any language that has for-loops and is non-functional but I have no idea how to do this in Haskell. I have a feeling that functions like `map`, `fold` or `sum` would help me here (admittedly I am not a 100% sure on how `fold` works). I hope there is an easy way to do this... please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here a proposal:

```
solution m1 m2 = sum $ zipWith diffSnd flatM1 flatM2
  where
    diffSnd t1 t2 = snd t1 - snd t2
    flatM1 = concat m1
    flatM2 = concat m2
```

I wrote it so that it's easier to understand the building blocks. 
The basic idea is to iterate simultaneously on our two lists of pairs using `zipWith`. Here its type:

```
zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
```

It means it takes a function with type `a -> b -> c`, a list of `a`'s and a list of `b`'s, and it returns a list of `c`'s. In other words, `zipWith` takes case of the iteration, you just have to specify what you want to do with every item the iteration yields, that in your case will be a pair of pairs (one from the first matrix, another one from the second).

The function passed to `zipWith` takes the `snd` element from each pair, and computes the difference. Looking back at `zipWith` signature you can deduce it will return a list of numbers. So the last thing we need to do is summing them, using the function `sum`.

There's one last problem. We actually do not have two lists of pairs to be passed to `zipWith`!, but two matrices. We need to "flatten" them in a list, preserving the order of the elements. That's exactly what `concat` does, hence the calls to that function in the definitions of `flatM1` and `flatM2`.

I suggest you look into the implementation of every function I mentioned to have a better grasp of how iteration is expressed by mean of recursion. HTH

Comment: Thanks! Worked great.

Comment: @Schytheron: If you need the difference as a matrix, and not just the sum, you can also use something like `zipWith (zipWith diffSnd)` instead of flattening the structure with `concat`. Also ``diffSnd = (-) `on` snd`` using `on` from `Data.Function`.